# How to get enum value of raw type from an enum class and a string in kotlin

Tags: generics, enums, kotlin

I have the following code in java:

```
Enum getEnumValue(Class<?> enumClass, String value) {
    return Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) enumClass, value);
}
```

How to rewrite this in Kotlin?

**Update**

`enumValueOf<>()` function is not applicable in this case because I don't know the actual type parameter, I only have a `Class<?>` object with unknown type (`Class<*>` in kotlin) and a name string. The Class is known to be enum:  `Class.isEnum` returns true. Using these two inputs, the java code above allows to obtain the value of the enum with a raw type. That's just what I need because I'm not interested in the specific type of the enum. But I can't figure out how to get the same result in kotlin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a pure Kotlin version:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun getEnumValue(enumClass: Class<*>, value: String): Enum<*> {
    val enumConstants = enumClass.enumConstants as Array<out Enum<*>>
    return enumConstants.first { it.name == value }
}
```

Note that it's not as efficient as the Java version. `java.lang.Enum.valueOf` uses a cached data structure while this version needs to create a new array to iterate over. Also this version is O(n) wheras the Java version is O(1) as it uses a dictionary under the hood.

There is an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18002) in the Kotlin bug tracker to support the same code as in Java which is scheduled for 1.3.

Here's a **really ugly** hack to workaround the generic type issue:

```
private enum class Hack

fun getEnumValue(enumClass: Class<*>, value: String): Enum<*> {
    return helper<Hack>(enumClass, value)
}

private fun <T : Enum<T>>helper(enumClass: Class<*>, value: String): Enum<*> {
    return java.lang.Enum.valueOf(enumClass as Class<T>, value)
}
```

A quick test shows that it's working but I wouldn't rely on it.

---

If the generic type is available, you can use the built-in function [`enumValueOf`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-value-of.html) (see also http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants):

```
enum class Color {
    Red, Green, Blue
}

enumValueOf<Color>("Red")
```

Comment: I'm aware of this function but it's not applicable in this case. I've updated the question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Performance is not of concern here - the code is executed once during the app startup, so this solution is just what I need.

Comment: any way to do this with enums with `Int` values?

Answer (score 4):

You can use below Kotlin code in your class for java code:

Kotlin function code:

```
private inline fun <reified T : kotlin.Enum<T>> getEnumValue(type: String?): T? {
    return java.lang.Enum.valueOf(T::class.java, type)
}
```

Example:

```
internal enum class MyEnum {
    MIDDLE_NAME
}
internal enum class MyEnumTwo {
    FIRST_NAME
}
internal enum class MyEnumThree {
    LAST_NAME
}


private fun demo(){

    System.out.println(getEnumValue<MyEnumTwo>("FIRST_NAME"))
    System.out.println(getEnumValue<MyEnum>("MIDDLE_NAME"))
    System.out.println(getEnumValue<MyEnumThree>("LAST_NAME"))

}
```

**Output:**

System.out: FIRST_NAME

System.out: MIDDLE_NAME

System.out: LAST_NAME

Old answer:

<s>fun getEnumValue(enumClass:Class<*>, value:String):Enum<*> {
          return Enum.valueOf>>(enumClass as Class>>, value)
       }</s>

Comment: That's pretty much what the standard `enumValueOf<>()` function does, but that's not what I need. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

`reified` really helpful here, we don't need class as parameter with it:

```
inline fun <reified E : Enum<E>> getEnumVariable(name: String): E {
    return enumValues<E>().firstOrNull { it.name == name }
        ?: error("No enum variable $name of type ${E::class.simpleName} found")
}
```

or

```
inline fun <reified E : Enum<E>> getEnumVariable(name: String): E {
    return enumValueOf<E>(name)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Kotlin has a built-in function for that:

```
enum class Fruits {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE,
    BANANA
}

Fruits.valueOf("APPLE")
```