# Get enum value based on it's ordinal in a generic class

Tags: generics, kotlin

Consider the below code:

```
class SegmentController<E : Enum<E>>() {

    fun getEnumForOrdinal(ordinal: Int) : E {
        //values is undefined?
        //how can I return the enum for the specified ordinal value?
        return E.values()[ordinal]
    }

    fun getOrdinalForEnum(enum: E): Int {
        //no problem getting the ordinal from the supplied E enum
        return enum.ordinal
    }

}
```

Its a generic class, taking any Enum as a template.

- How can I return an Enum value based on on ordinal in `getEnumForOrdinal()`?
- I would expect the `E.values()` to be available, but its not inside the generic class?

I did my research but cannot find any solution **based on the ordinal**, links I found:

- [How to get enum value of raw type from an enum class and a string in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416273/how-to-get-enum-value-of-raw-type-from-an-enum-class-and-a-string-in-kotlin)
- [Convert from enum ordinal to enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609860/convert-from-enum-ordinal-to-enum-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the enum's class as a constructor argument and access the enum values via `enumConstants`:

```kotlin
class SegmentController<E : Enum<E>>(private val clazz: Class<E>) {

    fun getEnumForOrdinal(ordinal: Int): E {
        return clazz.enumConstants[ordinal]
    }

    fun getOrdinalForEnum(e: Enum<E>): Int {
        return e.ordinal
    }
}

enum class SEGMENTS {A, B, C}

fun main() {
    val controller = SegmentController(SEGMENTS::class.java)
    println(controller.getOrdinalForEnum(SEGMENTS.B))
    println(controller.getEnumForOrdinal(1))
}
```

Alternatively, you could define `getEnumForOrdinal` as an `inline` function with a `reified` type parameter `E` and use `enumValues` to access the enum's values:

```kotlin
class SegmentController<E : Enum<E>>() {

    inline fun <reified E : Enum<E>> getEnumForOrdinal(ordinal: Int): E {
        return enumValues<E>()[ordinal]
    }

    fun getOrdinalForEnum(e: Enum<E>): Int {
        return e.ordinal
    }
}

enum class SEGMENTS {A, B, C}

fun main() {
    val controller = SegmentController<SEGMENTS>()
    println(controller.getOrdinalForEnum(SEGMENTS.B))
    println(controller.getEnumForOrdinal<SEGMENTS>(1))
}
```

See also: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants

A superb explanation of the `reified` keyword is given by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45952201/5095444).

> *I would expect the E.values() to be available, but its not inside the
>   generic class?*

The `values()` method is not available in the `Enum` [class](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Enum.kt).

Comment: Excellent answer!